# Testlink 1.9.16 Test Execution - Save Results button does not appear

Tags: testing, jira-rest-api, testlink

Updated Testlink 1.9.13 -> 1.9.16
Executing test function lost input fields for "Execution Notes" and "save result" -button. I found a bug: http://mantis.testlink.org/view.php?id=7812 My version includes that correction. But I still experience this :(

[Single test execution window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIt29.png)

Reason for upgrade was, updating JIRA and new version stopped supporting soup -integration to it. Now looks like this version REST -integration works, but executing test doesn't.

Anyone faced similar problem?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by investigating the upgrade process to 1.9.16 version. It was found out that `config.inc.php` from previous version was in place.

After updating new version of this config file, and modifying installation specific parameters in place. testExecution buttons appeared [test execution works, buja!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJHRZ.png)